# What is the range parameter in CallSpec for groovy?

Tags: groovy

groovy CallSpec has this range property:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/mock/interceptor/CallSpec.html#range

What does this range do? The groovy doc is too terse, honestly I can't extract any useful information from it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's internally used in `Demand`: https://github.com/apache/groovy/search?q=callspec ; Since you are most likely not searching for missing doc strings in five year old software: what problem are you facing with this class? Can you add the code, that shows your problem?

Comment: It lets you specify a range for the number of times the call is expected, e.g.:
https://gist.github.com/crazy4groovy/2979077#file-mockfor-groovy-L28
It is mentioned in Groovy in Action but if you are up for it, it would be a nice addition to the official doco here:
http://groovy-lang.org/testing.html#_mockfor_and_stubfor

Comment: Get it, so it is the number of times the call is expected, so the verify step can use this information to do verification. Thanks.